# What are tests to determine the number of technical replicates neccessary to reach the true mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics, replicability

I have the following scenario: I am working with a quite variable material, so I am using technical replicates to estimate the mean sample properties. To test how many replicas I need to converge to the true mean value, I tested a lot of replicas (~30) for one of my sample (I can´t do the same for all of them because of time constraints). Assuming the true mean is given by the maximum number of replicas, I now want to test what amount of replicas are needed to already get close to it.

I know there must be a test, where one takes the average of first 2, then 3, then 4, and so on, replicas, and plots them; afterwards randomly re-orders the data and does the same thing several times again. This way one ends up with an interval that finaly converges on the mean. However I just can´t remember the name of the method! Can anyone help me with that?

Or does anyone have other methods they would recomend me for this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You’re certain to get the wrong mean value, no matter how many measurements you make. However, you can g get close and quantify your uncertainty. How close do you want to be? $1mm?$ $1\mu m?$ $1pm?$ (Okay, maybe enough measurements gets you within a fraction of a Planck length. You probably can’t do that many.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to (empirical) bootstrapping?, See [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-05-introduction-to-probability-and-statistics-spring-2014/readings/MIT18_05S14_Reading24.pdf) and [here](http://www.jtrive.com/the-empirical-bootstrap-for-confidence-intervals-in-python.html) for example. You can use this method to derive a confidence interval for the "population mean". You need to assume the mean of the replica's is the same number as what you are after, but you already mentioned that in your question if I understand you correctly, when you say

> "Assuming the true mean is given by the maximum number of replicas".